# Do I need to explicitly add a war plugin section in POM?

Tags: maven

I want to generate a `war` package and this will do it by simply adding `<packaging>war<packaging>` into `pom.xml` and `mvn package` put the `.war` under `./target` directory.

My question, besides that `<packaging>war</packaging>`, do I also need to add this section into my `pom.xml`?

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes.

In detail:

Though the [`war` goal of the `maven-war-plugin` is bound to the `package` phase of a `war` project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) by default its [`attachClasses`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses) default value is `false`. To override this default value you have to declare the plugin in your POM as you mentioned. The same applies if you want to use a newer version (`3.0.0`) than [the one bound by default](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml) (`2.2` at the time of this writing).